# Is this Proof Correct: If $C$ is a Convex Set with Finite Volume, then $C$ is Bounded?

Tags: convex-geometry, combinatorial-geometry

**Question**

Prove that if $C$ is a convex set with non-empty interior, and it has finite volume, then $C$ is bounded.

**Attempt**

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $C$ is unbounded i.e. for $M>0, \lVert x \rVert >M$ for $x\in M$. Since $C$ is non-empty, there exists at least a point $p\in C$ such that $B(p,\epsilon)\subseteq C$ for $\epsilon >0$. This ball has a positive finite volume.

Since $C$ is convex, consider all points $x^\prime\in C$ such that $x^\prime = (1-\lambda)p+\lambda x = p+\lambda (x-p)$ for $x\in C$. If we scale $C$ from the point $p$ by a factor $\lambda >1$, then $x^\prime$ will still be in $C$. We will have $C^\prime \subseteq C$(since $C$ is unbounded). So, distances within $C$ are scaled by $\lambda$, and the volume of $C$ by $\lambda ^n$, where $n$ is the dimension of the space.

Since by our assumption $C$ is unbounded, we could choose an arbitrarily large $\lambda$ which would scale the volume of any subset with positive volume to an arbitrarily large $\lambda$ which would scale the volume of any subset with positive volume to an arbitrarily large volume. This means the volume of $C$ would be infinite. This contradicts the fact that $C$ has finite volume. So, we reject the assumption that $C$ is unbounded.

Hence, we conclude that $C$ is bounded.

Comment: In your question and title, you obviously mean "bounded" not "unbounded."

Comment: @MichaelCohen I just edited it

Comment: Hello. I'm not quite sure I understand your proof. I agree that if you scale $C$ by arbitrarily large $\lambda$ then its volume gets arbitrarily large. I don't see why this implies the volume of $C$ itself is infinite. In particular what is $C'$ and how do you know it's a subset of $C$? Where is your proof using the assumption that $C$ is unbounded? I think $C$ is unbounded means "for all $M > 0$, there is some $x \in C$ such that $\lVert x \rVert > M$".

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I mean if we scale $C$, we would have $C^\prime$. and we could make $C^\prime$ as large as possible.  And since $C$ is unbounded, we can still fit $C^\prime$ in $C$, leading to a contradiction. I am not particularly confident of this proof, and will welcome your help.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I think there's a mistake: "since $C$ is unbounded, $C'$ can still fit in $C$". $C$ being unbounded doesn't tell you it's unbounded "in every direction". An example of an unbounded set is $(0, 1) \times \Bbb R \subseteq \Bbb R^2$, but when you scale it it doesn't fit back in the original set. Your idea is not completely off, though. To answer this question I think you should prove "arbitrarily tall cones with a fixed base have arbitrarily large volume" (visualise $2$ or $3$ dimensions first). Do you see what I'm getting at? Can you fill in the details?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I seem to run into the same problem: Let the fixed base of the cone be in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Let point $v$, which is some distance above the base, be the vertex of the cone. If the cone $C$ is unbounded, then we can scale $C$ so that $v$ goes further away from the base of the cone. This means the volume of $C$ increases, since volume is proportional to the perpendicular height of the cone. Since we can make the volume of $C$ as large as we want ($C$ is unbounded), this contradicts the fact that $C$ has a finite volume. Hence, $C$ cannot be bounded.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Obviously, there is something I am missing. Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Any convex set will have non-void interior in its affine span.  So here we should assume first that the interior of $C$ is nonvoid.  Once we have that  we can show that if $C$ is unbounded, then $C$ has infinite volume. The reason is that if $C\supset B(0,r)$, and $\|x\|= d$, then the convex hull of $x \cup B(0,r)$ approaches infinity as $d\to \infty$. I think you sketched this argument yourself. I don't have now a clean way to show the fact about the volume, but it it will be larger than the volume of a pyramid with base a circular section of the ball, and height $d$ (that is the intution), so it grows like $\text{const}\times d$.

$\bf{Added:}$  now I see that  @Izaak van Dongen  aluded to the pyramid too in his comments, so apparently it is a natural thing.